# How can I get a TextView from a ListView WITHOUT Click?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm starting out in Android and creating a basic to-do-list using `ListActivity`. Essentially, every time an item (an entry) is clicked, the item is marked (or unmarked) in it's corresponding `SharedPreferences` file. In addition, the corresponding `TextView` is also slashed (or unslashed) using `setPaintFlags`, as follows:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)   {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    SharedPreferences savedList = this.getPreferences(0);
    String item = savedList.getString(position + "", "");

    if ( item.contains(checked) )   {
        item = item.replace(checked,"");
        SaveItem(item, position);   
        ((TextView)v).setPaintFlags( ((TextView)v).getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
    }
    else   {
        item = checked + item;
        SaveItem(item,position);
        ((TextView)v).setPaintFlags( ((TextView)v).getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }       
}
```

(The "checked" here is just a string.)
In the `OnCreate` method, to read the `SharedPreferences` file to reload the items in the checklist, and for whichever ones have been marked, I would like, again, to strike it out, as follows:

```
for (int i = 0;; i++){
    pos = i;
    listitems = savedList.getString(""+i,"");
    if (listitems.matches("")){ //if first entry in saved file is empty, stop the loop
        break;
    }
    else if(listitems.contains(checked)){
        listitems.replace(checked,"");
        listItems.add(listitems);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
        TextView textview = (TextView) (getListView()).getChildAt(i);
        textview.setPaintFlags( textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
    else{
        listItems.add(listitems);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, with two problems arising: first, even though I am remove the "checked" from those that are checked, the item appearing in `ListView` still has a "checked". And secondly, the strikes don't appear, leading me to believe that the corresponding `TextView` hasn't been picked up.

Edit: forgot to include something.

Answer (score 0):

The `View v` isn't a TextView, if your TextView have an id, you can use `v.findViewById` to find your target TextView on `onListItemClick`;

```
TextView textview = (TextView) (getListView()).getChildAt(i);
```

you also can use `getListView().getChildAt(i).findViewByid`

Comment: Wouldn't your final line return an integer? Whereas I'm looking to retrieve a TextView from the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

i don't get question properly but whatever i get that you want `Textview` from your  list item 
in your `onListItemClick` you can get your `Textview`

```
TextView textview = ((TextView) ((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(1));
```

Where `getChildAt(1)` **1** is index number of list item